# Objective-C: Unable to instantiate a class to create a UINavigationController subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm attempting to create (in XCode) a Tabbed Application, which houses in one of its tabs a UINavigationController, which is used to show a "FourthViewController", and then when a button is pressed within that "FourthViewController", a new "SlideViewController" is pushed onto the UINavigationController (phew!). I'm having problems understanding how to make the UINavigationController push a new ViewController from inside FourthViewController or SlideViewController. I'm including a flowchart and some code to try to make it more clear what I'm doing. (And for the record, it's an app for a restaurant, which is why there are names like "shrimpquesadilla.jpg".)

The following is a link to the flowchart, I don't have enough reputation to embed it in the post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjTT1.jpg

DemoTabbedAppDelegate.h

```
    @interface DemoTabbedAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,
                                     UITabBarControllerDelegate>
    {
        UINavigationController *globalUINavigationController;
    }
    ... //other syntheses
    @synthesize globalUINavigationController;
```

DemoTabbedAppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
                    (NSDictionary *)LaunchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        ... /creating the first three tab ViewControllers
        globalUINavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:
                    @"DemoTabbedFourthViewController" bundle:nil];
        ... //setting last tab title and image
        UIViewController *viewController4 = [[DemoTabbedFourthViewController alloc]
                    initWithNibName:@"DemoTabbedFourthViewController" bundle:nil];
        [globalUINavigationController pushViewController:viewController4 animated:YES];
        ... //Starting the TabBarController and making it the rootViewController
    }
```

DemoTabbedFourthView.m

```
    //initialization and all that junk
    - (void)goToSlide:(UIImage *)image
    {
        DemoTabbedSlideViewController *d = [[DemoTabbedSlideViewController alloc]
                                            initWithImage:image];
        [globalUINavigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"test");
        //what goes here to call push on the UINavigationController?
    }

    - (void)clickQuesadilla:(id)sender
    {
        [self goToSlide:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shrimpquesadilla.jpg"]];
    }
```

DemoTabbedSlideViewController

```
    - (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
    {
        self = [super init];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
        NSLog(@"test 2");
        return self;
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more information, I've tried to be as clear about this as possible. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be with how you are initializing your navigation controller.
When you instantiate your navigation controller, try using `initWithRootViewController:` instead of `initWithNibName:`.

Also, from inside your DemoTabbedFourthView's .m, you can get a pointer to the navigation controller it is in by accessing its `navigationController` property and then calling `pushViewController:animated:` from that:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
```

Comment: Holy cow, you're a genius, Pedro. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This type of application is practically a poster child for Storyboards. Is there some reason you prefer not to use them?

You could easily lay out a Storyboard with Segues between all of these views, and let the frameworks handle all of this navigation between views for you.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't learned how to use Storyboards yet. I started learning from a book as training for my new job, and about a third of the way through I was told to start work, so I'm winging it, and hoping to pick up knowledge along the way through trial and error. And, if nothing else, it's probably useful to know how to do this without Storyboards. No knowledge is bad knowledge. But thank you for your answer, I'll do research on Storyboards; I'm sure they'll make things much easier in the future.

Comment: The pace of change for iOS is still pretty high, with each new release bringing new framework features to the table. It's hard for authors to keep pace, thus lots of introductory material still teaches older techniques. But you're quite right: no knowledge is bad knowledge... Best of luck with your app!